# Is there a standard way to convert a java.util.function,Consumer<T> into a java.util.function.Function<T, Void>

Tags: java, java-8

I have a `Consumer<T>` that I'd like to convert into a `Function<T, Void>`.

I could achieve that by using

```
public <T> Function<T, Void> consumerToFunction(Consumer<T> consumer)
{
    return x -> {
        consumer.accept(x);
        return null;
    };
}
```

But I suspect that something like that might already exist in the JDK or perhaps in a common library.

Comment: No, don't think so, that looks right to me.  That said -- why do you want this?  `Function`s should generally be side-effect-free.

Comment: `consumer::accept`? EDIT: [nope](http://ideone.com/NUGYOj), void cannot be converted to Void. Also, `Void` and `T` are in the wrong order.

Comment: I have a `Consumer<T>` instance and the API I'm using requires a `Function<T, R>`. The call ends up returning the `R` to me. I don't need that `R` and can safely ignore it.

Comment: @user2357112 that does not work. `Function<String, Void> x = stringConsumer::accept;` > `incompatible types: bad return type in method reference void cannot be converted to java.lang.Void`

Comment: Your solution looks fine to me. I don't know of any easier way to convert between those two function types.

Comment: Can you describe the API you're using?  Does that API want side effects in functions you're using?

Comment: @LouisWasserman The API checks a bunch of validations and if they're good, the Function is called and the result returned. If they're not, an exception is thrown.

Comment: The only thing I would change, is to place the lambda expression right where you call `consumerToFunction` and get rid of that method…

Comment: My recent case for this was `java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.exceptionally(Function<Throwable, Void>)` (ie a handler for an exception thrown from a completable future that has no return value).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you need to adapt a `Consumer<T>` to a `Function<T, R>`.  You have created a good example of the [Adapter Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern).

> [T]he adapter pattern is a software design pattern that allows the interface of an existing class to be used from another interface.

You are letting a `Consumer` be used from a `Function`.

I know of no JDK built-in converter between functional interfaces, but this appears to be a good way of applying a standard pattern to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

A standard way doesn't exist, but this should do the trick:

```
Function<T, Void> adapt(final Consumer<T> consumer) {
    return t -> {
        consumer.accept(t);
        return null;
    };
}
```

This is following the Adapter Pattern mentioned in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29685206/8807741) from [@rgettman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1707091/rgettman).