# Pass scala function as java functional interface argument

Tags: java, scala, functional-programming

I have a java constructor which takes a functional interface as a parameter:

```
public ConsumerService(QueueName queue, Consumer<T> function) {
    super(queue);
    this.function = function;
}
```

I'm trying to use this constructor in scala but the compiler complains, saying it cannot resolve the constructor. I've tried the following ways:

```
val consumer = new ConsumerService[String](QueueName.CONSUME, this.process _)
val consumer = new ConsumerService[String](QueueName.PRODUCE, (s: String) => this.process(s))
```

I've also tried to cast the function at runtime - but that leaves me with a ClassCastException:

```
val consumer = new ConsumerService[String](QueueName.CONSUME, (this.process _).asInstanceOf[Consumer[String]])
```

How can I pass a scala function as a java functional interface parameter?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29684894/is-there-a-standard-way-to-convert-a-java-util-function-consumert-into-a-java but there is no real answer there either...

Comment: That's a different thing, as there is no Scala involved

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to create a `Consumer`:

```
val consumer = new ConsumerService[String](QueueName.CONSUME, 
  new Consumer[String]() { override def accept(s: String) = process(s) })
```

Answer (score 5):

Another way is to use a following library:

https://github.com/scala/scala-java8-compat.

With that in your project once you import:

`import scala.compat.java8.FunctionConverters._`

you can now write:

`asJavaConsumer[String](s => process(s))`

which in your code should go like this:

`val consumer = new ConsumerService[String](
   QueueName.CONSUME,
   asJavaConsumer[String](s => process(s))
)`